Как передать Cache-Control в get запросе в RTC query?
Всем привет, недавно начал изучать rtc query и сейчас изучаю работу с кэшем, может кто-то подскажет как лучше отправлять cache-control в запросе , в сети увидел такой вариант, кто-то может подсказать, правильно ли так?)

const exampleApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'exampleApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: '/api',
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getExample: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/example',
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetExampleQuery } = exampleApi;
export default exampleApi.reducer; ```
  

    

